# How to deal with unequal sample sizes in order to avoid bias?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Let's say I have 5 companies that report their revenue for different markets. Some companies have fewer observations than others. Sample size for each company is 10000+, but the revenue reporting are also very large numbers. I do not know whether it is their actual revenue or whether they just did not report all of their revenue. I want to identify the companies that have the biggest revenue.

How can I do that? If I just look at the companies that have highest earnings there is a chance of selective bias. Is there a way to normalize data?

Comment: I don't think the nature of the dataset is clear. How do companies have 10000+ observations for revenue?

Comment: Basically each sale in a month was recorded.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you ask. Is that you don't know the true revenue from their reportings and so you want to infer the revenue from the earnings?

Answer (score 0):

How about calculating a grouped revenue mean per month? Group data by company, and calculate the mean revenue in each group. Because you said each record is a month's revenue, I assume that the mean of revenue column in each group gives you the mean revenue of each company.
If each company has different sets of markets, you can group on companies then group on markets. Calculate the mean revenue per month for different markets and sum up the mean monthly revenues from different markets under each company. And you get total monthly revenues of each company's markets.